# IE styling in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

When I load the default ST app in IE10, styling is non-existant even with the following defined in app.json:

If I load in Chrome, the styling is present. I have carried out an app refresh too.
I'm using ST2.3.1 with cmd 4

```
"css": [
         {
            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
            "platform": ["chrome", "safari", "android", "firefox"],
            "theme": "Default",
            "update": "delta"
        },
         {
            "path": "resources/css/wp.css",
            "platform": ["ie10"],
            "theme": "Default",
            "update": "delta"
        }
```

If I look in **myapp\resources\css** I can see **app.css** and **wp.css**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Sencha [theming](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/theming) guide, you may need to change "theme" from "Default" to "Windows" in your second JSON object. Then do a *sencha app refresh* and try again.

Comment: Ok I'll try this. Why do you have to change the CSS file AND the theme?

Comment: Without going into a long-winded answer, the core Sencha Touch framework sets a bunch of stuff based on the configured theme... so it's more than just CSS.

Comment: Can I set CSS to app.css and Theme to 'Windows' then? If they do, I think this is bad design as changing one property is reliant on another property being set too.